# Hover effect won't resize my button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was trying to initiate the same effect like this:

[image]

As you can see when the mouse was hovered to the button the button has this scaling and fading white effect.

I tried to the same thing on my button bootstrap by customizing my css but for some reason it won't scale up and it give me the effect of scaling and fading white effect like you see there.

So far here's what I've tried:

```css
body {
  background: #6FDC9C !important;
}

a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.signup{
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #C056BB;
}

a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.signup:hover{
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 0 0 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  outline-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  outline-offset: 15px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #427388; 
}

a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.signup:hover::after{
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
    transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
    opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg signup btn-animated" href="#" role="button">SIGN UP</a>
```

But this CSS did not attain what I want. Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: add `transition`

Comment: I've added transition but still did not work

Answer (score 0):

**SOMETHING MISSING IN YOUR CSS**
You need to **create the virtual .btn FIRST** that scales up and disappears, leaving the original .btn. before using the :hover::after:
In your case:

```
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.signup::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;/*you may not need this!*/
/*inherit dimensions as is*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
/*you can change your original border-radius too */
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute;
/*inherit dimensions as is and position it where the original button seats*/
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
/*depending on your z-index, send it behind the original button*/
    z-index: -1;
    /* the transition displayed seems to be using 2seconds and ease-in*/
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

Add this to your code and give feedback!

Answer (score -1):

I usually do a [different approach](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/scale-on-hover-with-webkit-transition/) when I want to scale on hover, delete de `:hover::after` and add `transition: all .2s ease-in` to the class and `transform: scale(1.1)` to the hover.

```
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.signup{
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #C056BB;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}



a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.signup:hover{
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 0 0 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  outline-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  outline-offset: 15px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #427388; 
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: It scales the button when hovered but won't displaying any fading growing effect like in the example.

Comment: Is that button stylingfrom a template? Maybe adding a class does the fading stuff. If not I can recommend you Hover.css made by Ian Lunn for the hover styles: http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

Comment: as much as possible i dont want to bombard my app with css frameworks

Comment: Well you could check the source code and copy the hover you want, every effect is well documented by the author, here you have the link to the .css file https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover/blob/master/css/hover.css